# Selenium: Element Not Visible Error when RDC minimized

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I'm running WATIR automated tests using Selenium WebDriver on a Windows XP remote desktop, and I noticed that when I minimize the RDC I start getting random `Element is not currently visible` errors for my assertions. If I leave the RDC maximized and sit and baby-sit the tests ,they all run fine. I have found that the combination of software versions below, even though newer versions exist, give me the least number of compatibility issues.

ruby (1.8.7)
selenium-webdriver (2.21.2)
watir-webdriver (0.6.2)
firefox (10.0.2)

Thoughts on why the tests only run with the RDC visible?

Comment: RDC? what are you meaning by that?    what if it's not maximized, but just a window?  will things work then?  if so that might be a workaround.

Comment: trying adding some delay before locating element..would be useful to see some of your code..

Answer (score 1):

When you minimize a Remote Desktop session it becomes GUI-less and GUI actions will fail.

The solution that we use for [RIATest](http://www.cogitek.com/riatest.html) is as follows (not sure if it will help with Selenium but it should).

In the client machine from which you connect do this:

1. Close all Remote Desktop sessions.
2. Open Registry Editor.
3. Go to key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client (or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client if you want to set it for all users).
4. Add a DWORD value RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized and set it to 2.
5. Close Registry Editor.